# Adding Comments to Parameter in DLL

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I had created a DLL in .NET ,which includes several function.Now I am suing this DLL in another App
[image]

I want that whenever the client uses my DLL,somesort of comments must be shown that shows return type,Parameters etc.like this
[image]

i see people this using XML files.Is there any alternative way?
Thanks in meekness

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
/// <summary>
/// This method does something.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="zain">Zain to be processed.</param>
/// <returns>True if it went okay, false otherwise.</returns>
```

Answer (score 8):

You need to use [XML documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b2s063f7.aspx) specified in comments before the member declaration.

```
/// <summary>Some stuff here</summary>
/// <remarks>Some remarks</remarks>
/// <param name="foo">The foo to gronk</param>
```

Then go into your project properties and enable building an XML file alongside your library in the "Build" tab. Distribute that along with your DLL, and Visual Studio will display your content.

Comment: This is the most accurate answer.

Answer (score 2):

Use /// at the start of the method declarations:

```
/// <summary>
/// This method does something.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="foo">Foo value to be processed.</param>
/// <returns>True if it went okay, false otherwise.</returns>
public bool DoSomething(int foo)
{
    if (foo > 0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: ...`return foo > 0`... couldn't help myself.

Answer (score 1):

As has been stated, you can add XML documentation at the beginning of each public member:

```
/// <summary>
/// This is the summary for your method.
/// </summary>
public void MyMethod()
{
    /// your code here...
}
```

There are a host of tools to aide in the process.  Check out [GhostDoc](http://submain.com/products/ghostdoc.aspx) for generating comments and [Sandcastle](http://shfb.codeplex.com/) for creating help files or web pages from it.